# Как вызвать функцию внутри класса php

Tags: php, ооп, классы

Есть такой код, часть кода с Yii2

```
public static function selectAllList() {
    //Получаем группы с БД
    $data = CatalogNomenclature::find()->select('id, name AS text')->where(['is_folder' => true])->asArray()->all();
    //Задаем id в качестве ключа, а text в качестве значения
    $array = ArrayHelper::map($data, 'id', 'text');
    //Добавим к массиву корень
    ArrayHelper::setValue($array, 0, 'Корень');

    return $this->separator($array);
}

protected function separator($array) {
    var_dump($array);
    die;
}
```

Почему выдает ошибку? Using $this when not in object context
Как мне вызвать separator в selectAllList?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что метод `selectAllList` у Вас статический. Сделайте метод `separator` статическим и используйте вместо `return $this->separator($array);` `return self::separator($array);`

Либо `public function selectAllList()`

Comment: Спасибо. Не до конца еще понимаю ООП )))